# Stuck getting sample C function working on Windows version

Tags: windows, postgresql

v9.6, win server 2012, vs 2015
successfully compiled and linked as x64.

Create function fails saying that there is no 'add_one' function in the dll.

```
postgres=# create function add_one(integer) returns integer as
'win32project1',' add_one' language c strict; 

ERROR:  could not find function "add_one" in file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/win32project1.dll"
```

The function seems to be there though, dumpbin says

> ```
>       1    0 000112CB Pg_magic_func = @ILT+710(Pg_magic_func)
>       2    1 00011087 pg_finfo_add_one = @ILT+130(pg_finfo_add_one)
>       3    2 00011190 pg_finfo_add_one_float8 = @ILT+395(pg_finfo_add_one_float8)
>       4    3 000110F5 pg_finfo_concat_text = @ILT+240(pg_finfo_concat_text)
>       5    4 000112C1 pg_finfo_copytext = @ILT+700(pg_finfo_copytext)
>       6    5 0001107D pg_finfo_makepoint = @ILT+120(pg_finfo_makepoint)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

OK, there needs to be 2 functions exported for each function, the meta data function `pg_finfo_xxx` plus the actual function itself `xxx`.

The standard headers for pg functions compiling mark the meta data function with PGDLLEXPORT but the forward declaration of the actual function is not marked that way. I dont see how this could ever work.

```
#define PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(funcname) \
Datum funcname(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS); \
extern PGDLLEXPORT const Pg_finfo_record * CppConcat(pg_finfo_,funcname)(void); \
const Pg_finfo_record * \
CppConcat(pg_finfo_,funcname) (void) \
{ \
    static const Pg_finfo_record my_finfo = { 1 }; \
    return &my_finfo; \
} \
extern int no_such_variable
```

But I made it work by doing

```
#define PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(funcname) \
PGDLLEXPORT Datum funcname(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS); \
extern PGDLLEXPORT const Pg_finfo_record * CppConcat(pg_finfo_,funcname)(void); \
const Pg_finfo_record * \
CppConcat(pg_finfo_,funcname) (void) \
{ \
    static const Pg_finfo_record my_finfo = { 1 }; \
    return &my_finfo; \
} \
extern int no_such_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your source file, but it should contain this:

```
extern PGDLLEXPORT Datum add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one);
```

Then it will probably work.

I have started a [discussion on the hackes mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B539300BD@ntex2010a.host.magwien.gv.at) to implement [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967261/6464308) in PostgreSQL, but it seems that with the build process that PostgreSQL is using (generate and use export definition files) this causes at least warnings, so we have given up on it.

The other option you have is to create and use an export definition file like PostgreSQL does, then you can do without the PGDLLEXPORT decorations altogether.

Comment: i copied the source file directly from the 9.6 doc page https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xfunc-c.html#XFUNC-C-DYNLOAD

Comment: yr suggestion does work, but if the PG_FUNCTION_INFO had the PGDLLEXPORT in it then this extra line would not be needed

Comment: The sample in the documentation does not seem to target Windows. That's a mistake. I'll propose a patch.

Comment: Follow [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B539300BD@ntex2010a.host.magwien.gv.at) to see what the hackers have to say to that.

Comment: sigh - "nobody complained so far. And while we are at it let make sure it doesnt work on windows'

Comment: Don't be unfair. We tried hard to make it happen, but Windows is just too weird.